# How many time is the inner loop running?

Tags: loops, execution

```
for(i=1, count=0;i<=n;i=i+k)
   for(j=1;j<=k;j++)
      count++;
```

I can't figure out how many times the inner for loop is executing.
I need the answer **in terms of n and k**

Comment: Well, how many times do you expect the outer loop to execute? And for each iteration of the outer loop, how many times do you expect the inner loop to execute?

Comment: Did you run the program with different values for `n` and `k` an evaluate `count`? This should give you a hint.

Comment: You could cheat and enclose your code into a working program, then display the result.

Comment: Isn't that what `count` tells you?

Comment: Yes, @Turing85 I did execute the code.
There was a clear pattern.

But if I were to solve by hand, how do I get a mathematical formula for directly counting the number of executions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the the two loops individually.

The outer loop starts with `i=1`, and increments it by `k` in each iteration, until it's greater than `n`. In other words it can run `n/k` times, or, to be accurate, `floor(n/k)` times, since a loop can't run a non-whole number of times.

The inner loop is relatively simpler - it starts with `j=1` and increments it by one in each iteration until it's greater than `k`, for a total of `k` times.

Put these two together and you'll get `floor(n/k)*k`.

**EDIT:**
As pointed out in the comment, this analysis is true if `n>=k`. If `n<k` the outer loop will run exactly once. I.e., the total times run would be: `max(1, floor(n/k))*k`.

Comment: And complexity is `O(n)` (even if there is an inner loop).

Comment: What if n=1 and say, k=2?

Comment: @Jarod42 Indeed.

Comment: @Ayazzia01 Good catch! See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: `floor(n/k) * k`. To check it exactly, I think you can print  with print.